# No se identifica struct... en otro file XCODE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

solicito la ayuda de esta comunidad de profesionales para atender la siguiente inquietud.

Quiero programar un evento de boton para cambiar de pantalla, he creado un file llamado konstant con el siguiente codigo:

```
import Foundation

struct Konstants {
struct Storyboard {
   static let homesViewController = "HomesViewController"
}}
```

Sin embargo quiero llamarlo en otro file llamado sign up con el siguiente codigo:

```
func transitionToHome() {
    let homesViewController =
    
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Konstants.homesViewController ) as?
    HomesViewController
    
    view.window?.rootViewController = homesViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

pero me sale el siguiente error cannot find "konstants" in scope.
Alguien sabe como solicionar esto? agradezco mucho su ayuda.

[image: Pantallazo de error]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una estructura dentro de otra estructura y la llamada no es la correcta ya que solo haces referencia al nombre de la primera estructura y la variable se encuentra en la segunda estructura.

Debes hacer referencia al segundo nombre también en la llamada:

```
storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Konstants.Storyboard.homesViewController ) as? HomeViewController
```

La otra solución desde mi punto de vista es usar `enums` para una mejor comprensión del código:

```
enum ViewControllersName: String {
    case homeViewController = "HomeViewController"
}
```

Y para instanciar el `ViewController` solo llamas al `enum` y con el `rawValue` obtienes el valor:

```
storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: ViewControllersName.homeViewController.rawValue) as? HomeViewController
```